# Count records for Blog in Ruby on Rails - Easy Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, blogs

I am new to rails so sorry for the simple question. I have followed several tutorials and set up a blog with comments (even using a little AJAX - Ha proud of myself). I have done some customizing and right now I am trying to display in the index.html.erb a comment count that is a clickable link that takes to you the show.html.erb page. Here is what I did so far and not sure it is right. In the comments_controller I have added the following:

```
  def count
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.count(params[:comment])
  end
```

First question is this the correct def to count comments associated with a particular post. Second question is how do I then call it in my index.html.erb page where I have the following:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render :partial => post %>
  <%= link_to 'View & Add Comments', post %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see I am currently using a link_to reference to get to the page but ideally would like it to show something like: Comments (8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of that controller method - replacing your current link_to for example:

```
<%= link_to "View & Add Comments (#{post.comments.count})" %>
```

If you already have the `@post` object to get the number of comments you just need to call `comments.count`. And if you are unfamiliar with string interpolation, [this link](http://railsreal.blogspot.com/2007/03/shortening-code-via-string.html) might help.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was so much simpler than I was making it.

Comment: Sure thing! I added a blurb about string interpolation just in case you haven't seen it before.

Comment: That's timely because I was just trying to figure out how to call that count to place anywhere without a link. I appreciate it.

Comment: One more request...since you seem to be a rails badass...if you have a second head over to my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753227/reverse-order-of-display-of-blog-entries-and-comments-ruby-on-rails and look at the top answer and my comment/question about AJAX. If you don't have time I understand. Just thought I would throw it out there as I am trying to hammer through a lot tonight.